# PHP debug build off in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

Any idea how I should solve this problem?

I tried reinstall my XAMPP and my xdebug but it still show off on `phpinfo()`.

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 1):

Debug build is not xdebug.

You say debug build is off (which it should unless you are [developing a PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.environment.php)) but then mention xdebug which is a completely different thing than the [--with-debug](http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php) option.

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I assume you want to enable xdebug. So you need to add `zend_extension=/path/to/xdebug.dll` in your php.ini or in the xdebug.ini in your additional dirs folder.

Please see https://xdebug.org/docs/install for installation instructions and full docs.